# Постепенное удаление случайных элементов массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть 8 html страниц, нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки `#okBtn` на любой из этих страниц, вызывался скрипт, который случайно выбирал следующую страницу.

---

Делаю это так:

1) Есть массив `testTotal` который изначально равен [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] и занесен в localStorage в json формате.

2)После нажатия на кнопку выбираю случайный элемент из полученного с localStorage десериализованного массива.

3)После выбора, удаляю этот элемент из массива и сохраняю полученный массив обратно в localStorage

4)Перехожу ну случайно полученную страницу.

5)Все по новой

---

Но иногда элементы вообще не удаляются, а иногда удаляются не те.

```
//Получаем массив из local storage
var testTotal = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("TestComplite"));

    $('#okBtn').click(function(){
        //Выбор случайного элемента из массива
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * testTotal.length);
        //Поиск выбранного элемента для удаления
        for (var i = 0; i < testTotal.length; i++) {
          if (testTotal[i] == testTotal[rand]) {
            testTotal.splice(testTotal[i], 1);
            //После удаления, сохраняем измененный массив
            window.localStorage.setItem("TestComplite", JSON.stringify(testTotal));
            //Переходим на случайно выбранную страницу
            window.location.replace("t" + rand + ".html");
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Переместите  определение testtotal в обработчик и уберите цикл: testTotal.splice(rand, 1) - этого хватит

Comment: @Дмытрык Точно, спасибо

Comment: @Дмытрык Но что-то все равно не удаляется тот элемент, который был выбран случайно и иногда случайно выбирается 0, хотя массив с определенными элементами внутри

Comment: Подумайте над разницей между индексом массива и содержимым, которое находится по этому индексу. Мне с телефона неудобно код писать.... ну и про метод splice почитайте

Comment: @Дмытрык ааа, вот зачем я цикл тогда делал))

Comment: Цикл тут не нужен

Comment: @Дмытрык а как тогда найти элемент в массиве, значение которого равно рандомному числу rand

Comment: метод array.includes

Comment: Нл у вас, какой-то неправильный подход к задаче. Зачем искать по рандомному содержимому, если можно по рандомному индексу

Comment: @Дмытрык не, дело в том, что длина массива должна меняться, за счет удаления ранее выбранных элементов, и поэтому элемент внутри  не всегда 
будет равен индексу

Comment: "Но иногда элементы вообще не удаляются, а иногда удаляются не те." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor выводил в консоль массив, после удаления

Comment: Было бы полезно увидеть, что выводилось в консоль: массив после чтения из `localStorage`, значение `rand`, массив после удаления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `splice()` удаляет/изменяет элемент из массива и в качестве возвращаемого значения содержит массив из удаленных элементов. Если был удален один элемент, то вернется массив из одного элемента.

```
// Оригинальный массив. Нужен, если:
//   а) `localStorage` пуст;
//   б) массив обнулился после метода `splice`
const ORIGINAL = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

$('#okBtn').click(function() {
    let testTotal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TestComplite')) || []

    // Если массив пуст, создаем новый.
    if (!testTotal.length) {
        testTotal = Array.from(ORIGINAL)
    }

    // Определяем случайный индекс в массиве.
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * testTotal.length)
    // Удаляем из массива элемент по индексу,
    // и берем первый из возвращенного массива
    // удаленных элементов.
    // В нашем случае это первый и единственный - [0]
    let current = testTotal.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]

    localStorage.setItem('TestComplite', JSON.stringify(testTotal))

    console.log('current:', current, 'total:', testTotal)

    // window.location.replace('t' + current + '.html')
});
```

Примерное содержимое консоли:

```
current: 1 total: (7) [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
current: 6 total: (6) [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
current: 5 total: (5) [2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
current: 2 total: (4) [3, 4, 7, 8]
current: 8 total: (3) [3, 4, 7]
current: 7 total: (2) [3, 4]
current: 3 total: [4]
current: 4 total: []
```

Вариант без зацикливаний:

```
let testTotal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TestComplite')) || Array.from(ORIGINAL)

// Если массив пуст, переходим на страницу `end`.
if (!testTotal.length) {
  window.location.replace('end.html')
}
```

После перехода на страницу `end.html` необходимо помнить о том, что массив в `localStorage` пуст.

Comment: А как сделать, так чтобы когда total = [] совершался переход на страницу end.html

Comment: Проще простого, там добавить, там убрать.

Comment: добавил вот это: `if (current != undefined) {
    window.location.replace('t' + current + '.html')
  }
  else {
    window.location.replace('end.html')
  }` **вместо** `if (!testTotal.length)` а то, когда массив становился равен [] переходило на страницу  `'t' + undefined+ '.html'`

Comment: А вы на `end.html` сбрасываете массив или удаляете `localStorage.removeItem('TestComplite')`?

Comment: Получается, так что я обновляю его до начала выполнения этого скрипта. Но я понял о чем вы, спасибо!